# Separating php form values

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form and on submit, it goes to submit.php.

The input text looks like this:

```
<input name="hpno[1]" type="text" maxlength="3" size="3" /> - <input name="hpno[2]" type="text" maxlength="8" size="13" />
```

I need to store the data as per this format (010) 5839539.

Tried putting this in the submit.php

$hpno = implode('-', $_POST['hpno']); but this gives the output 010-5839539.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could help to prevent an SQL injection like this:

```
$hpno = mysql_real_escape_string("(" . $_POST['hpno[1]'] . ") " . $_POST['hpno[2]']);
```

This will give you the formatting you need and scrub the input (though it's not perfect, or bullet-proof).

Answer (score 1):

`$(hpno) = '(' . implode(') ', $_POST['hpno']);` ?

Sorry, rusty with my PHP. Let me know what that puts out, especially if it's just an error.

Comment: this would place brackets in both hpno[1] and hpno[2] but thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be in the format `(xxx) xxxxxxx`, you'll have to do something like this:

```
$hpno = '('.$_POST["hpno[1]"].') '.$_POST["hpno[2]"];
```

You mentioned that you would be storing the data, so be careful if you're storing this in a database, you're clearly vulnerable to an injection attack this way.